# C# WaitForCompletionAsync

Tags: c#, azure

I saw some people who are using Azure invoke methods like:

```
var res = await func();
await res.WaitForCompletionAsync();
```

If await is already supposed to wait until the returned task is complete, then why is there a need for the `WaitForCompletionAsync` call?

Comment: It sounds like some other `async` operation is itself producing the `ValueTask<Response<T>>`  result, and then `WaitForCompletionAsync` is awaiting *that* task.  What does `func()` do here?

Comment: I tried making it a pseudo code example. I saw it in a code where the Func returns a Task<RecoverDeletedSecretOperation> . Not sure what RecoverDeletedSecretOperation actually is

Comment: Is `RecoverDeletedSecretOperation` something custom to that codebase?  I'm not seeing anything by that name when I search online.  But presumably if you're looking at code which uses that class then you can examine where it's referencing that class?

Comment: I believe its something specific for Azure Key vault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases in which `func()` initiates a long running operation on Azure, like provisioning a resource. So the first line is to start the long running operation on Azure.

```
var res = await func();
```

and the second line

```
await res.WaitForCompletionAsync();
```

waits for the operation on Azure to complete. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.operation-1.waitforcompletionasync?view=azure-dotnet) regarding `WaitForCompletionAsync`:

> This method will periodically call UpdateStatusAsync till HasCompleted is true, then return the final result of the operation.

So it is a helper function you can call so you do not need to write the polling mechanism yourself.

A typical example is `var status = await blobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceUri, null, cToken.Token);`

As the name implies, it starts an operation, and `WaitForCompletionAsync` can be used to await the completion of that operation.

Comment: NGL, but this _duplication of async concepts_ in a single method call is a very poor API design choice and will throw-off novices entirely...

Comment: @Dai yes, but most times the actual name of `func()` is **StartXXX()**, that might be an indicator that completion can be awaited

Comment: If that's the case then why is the second line await res.WaitForCompletionAsync() and not just await res? or is res not of type Task?

Comment: You do not await res, you await the Task that represents the (what's basically a spin-wait, I guess?) result polling operation. But I wonder if you could craft "res" to have a GetAwaiter() ....

Comment: You mean like this @CodeMonkey : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ti5yn1 ?

Comment: @Fildor but you await a task like the first line in the example.. what makes the 2nd line different?

Comment: Ah,you mean, you'd have just one call with one await?

Answer (score 1):

> If await is already supposed to wait until the returned task is
> complete, then why is there a need for the WaitForCompletionAsync
> call?

Reason being the operations are asynchronous on the Azure side. When you submit a request to Azure, it accepts the request and then completes the request asynchronously. By using `WaitForCompletionAsync`, you are actually waiting for the operation to complete on Azure side.

This method will periodically poll the status of the request and the method will be completed once the request is completed (either successful or failed).

Comment: Oh so the return value of the client side task is actually the task running on the server side?

Comment: Yeah, you can think it is something like that.

Comment: Then why won't the second line be just "await res;" instead of "await res.WaitForCompletionAsync()?

Comment: Because res is not awaitable. The Task (or ValueTask) returned by `res.WaitForCompletionAsync()` is.